# How to plot dielectric susceptibility and scattering intensity for thin film superconductor?

Tags: plotting, physics

I would like to plot the spatially varying (along the z-axis) dielectric susceptibility $\chi(z)$ of a thin film ($La_2CuO_4$) on top of a substrate ($SrTiO_3$) and the resultant scattering intensity when resonant soft x-ray scattering is performed on it. The graphs that I would like to replicate are: 
[image: Susceptibility Plots and Interference fringes]
The equations given to me are:
$$\chi(q) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi(z) e^{iqz} dz$$
where the momentum transfer $q = \frac{4\pi sin(\theta)}{\lambda}$ and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the incident x-ray photon.

For the scattering intensity, the paper details that for an isotropic film of thickness L with susceptibility $\chi_F$ on a substrate with susceptibility $\chi_S$, the integral for $\chi(q)$ has the value:$$\chi(q) = \frac{\chi_F}{iq} (1+e^{-iqL})-\frac{\chi_S}{iq + \eta}$$
where a convergence factor $e^{-\eta z}$ attenuates the substrate at infinite distances. If the film is anisotropic, then the susceptibility is a tensor: $$\chi(q)=\left(\begin{matrix}\chi_{ab}(q) & 0\\0 & \chi_c(q)\end{matrix}\right)$$
Then, the scattering matrix element M, incorporating polarization effects becomes:$$M = \epsilon_1\cdot\chi(q)\cdot\epsilon_2$$
where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are the incident and scattered polarizations of the x-ray photon. The values of the susceptibilities are as follows:$\chi_s = 1$, $\chi_F^c = 1.03$, $\chi_F^{ab} = 1.16 (\text{at prepeak})$, $\chi_F^{ab} = 1.78 (\text{at the $CuL_{3/2}$ peak})$.
And we can get the scattering intensity interference fringes from $|M|^2$.

I am currently facing issues in numerically implementing the attenuation factor in the susceptibility graph to obtain the sloping. I am also unsure as to how I can simulate the smoothing over 20 Angstroms at the substrate. Also, for the scattering intensity portion, I am also unable to get the same plots as graph B. My current code is listed below:

```
h = 6.62607015*10^-34;(*** Js ***)
c = 299792458; (* in ms*)
\[Omega] = 933*1.6*10^-19;(* energy of incoming photon in J *)
\[Lambda] = (h c)/\[Omega];(*incoming photon wavelength in SI units*)


L = 23.2*10^-9;(* m*)
\[Eta] = 9.14 10^4.5;

XFilmSpatial = 1.78
XSubSpatial = 1 (*Without attenuation constant*)
ListStepPlot[{{-8200, XFilmSpatial}, {-8000, XSubSpatial}}, Right, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Susceptibility Profile for La2CuO4 Film and STO Substrate", 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"\[Chi]", None}, {"z-coordinates, Angstrom", None}}];

(*Introducing attenuation constant*)
Plot[E^(-\[Eta]*z), {z, -8200 10^-10, -7800 10^-10}, 
  PlotRange -> Full];
(*Using Piecewise function to plot film and substrate \
susceptibilities*)
(*Plot[Piecewise[{XFilmSpatial,{-8200 10^10<=z<=-8000 10^-10}}, \
{XSubSpatial*\[ExponentialE]^(-\[Eta]*z ),{-8000 10^-10<=-7800 \
10^-10}}],
{z,-8300 10^-10,-7700 10^-10}]*)
XSubAtt[z_] := XSubSpatial*E^(-\[Eta]*z)
Plot[XSubAtt[z], {z, -8000 10^-10, -7800 10^-10}]
Plot[Piecewise[{{XFilmSpatial, -8200 10^-10 < 
     z < -8000 10^-10}, {E^(-\[Eta]*z), -8000 10^-10 <= 
     z <= -7800 10^-10}}, {z, -8200 10^-10, -8000 10^-10}], {z, -8200 \
10^-10, -7700 10^-10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-8200 10^-10, -7700 10^-10}, {0.80, 1.8}}]

(*Using 2D polarization vector and analytical susceptibility*)
\[Omega]1 = 535*1.6*10^-19;(* energy of incoming photon in J *)
\[Lambda]1 = (
  h c)/\[Omega]1; (*incoming photon wavelength in SI units*)

XFAB1 = 1.78; (*Susceptibility of film in AB plane*)
XFC = 1.03; (*Susceptibility of film in C plane*)
XFAB2 = 1; 
XS = 1; (*Susceptibility of substrate*)
q[\[Theta]_] := (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda];
XAB1[\[Theta]_] := 
  XFAB1/(I (
     4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]1) (1 + 
      E^(-I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]1 L)) - XS/(
   I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]1 + \[Eta]);
XC1[\[Theta]_] := 
  XFC/(I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]1) (1 + 
      E^(-I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]1 L)) - XS/(
   I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]1 + \[Eta]);
M1[\[Theta]_] := 
 XAB1[\[Theta]]*(Sin[\[Theta] Degree])^2 - 
  XC1[\[Theta]]*(Cos[\[Theta] Degree])^2
ScattIntensity1[\[Theta]_] := Abs[M1[\[Theta]]]^2
(*For 933eV photon*)
\[Omega]2 = 933*1.6*10^-19;
\[Lambda]2 = (h c)/\[Omega]2;
XAB2[\[Theta]_] := 
  XFAB1/(I (
     4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]2) (1 + 
      E^(-I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]2 L)) - XS/(
   I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]2 + \[Eta]);
XC2[\[Theta]_] := 
  XFC/(I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]2) (1 + 
      E^(-I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]2 L)) - XS/(
   I (4  \[Pi] Sin[\[Theta] Degree])/\[Lambda]2 + \[Eta]);
M2[\[Theta]_] := 
 XAB2[\[Theta]]*(Sin[\[Theta] Degree])^2 - 
  XC2[\[Theta]]*(Cos[\[Theta] Degree])^2
ScattIntensity2[\[Theta]_] := Abs[M2[\[Theta]]]^2
Plot[ScattIntensity1[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 15, 85}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2*10^-19}, PlotLabel -> "Analytical Evaulation", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Scattering Intensity", 
    None}, {"Angle of Incidence, \[Theta](deg)", None}}]
Plot[ScattIntensity2[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 15, 85}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2*10^-19}, PlotLabel -> "Analytical Evaulation", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Scattering Intensity", 
    None}, {"Angle of Incidence, \[Theta](deg)", None}}]
Plot[{ScattIntensity1[\[Theta]], 
  ScattIntensity2[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 15, 85}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2*10^-19}, PlotLabel -> "Analytical Evaulation", 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Scattering Intensity", 
    None}, {"Angle of Incidence, \[Theta](deg)", None}}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"\[Lambda]=535eV", "\[Lambda]=933eV"}]]
```

How can I simulate these graphs properly using Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Your code evaluates and plots various graphs and it seems well organized. When you say: "How can I simulate graphs properly..." do you have a math/computation question or are you seeking advice on formatting for your graphs to mimic the plots shown? Please ask a specific question to get a focused answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I am seeking advice on how I can mimic the plots shown, as my code is not producing the desired result. In particular, how can I numerically implement an attenuation factor inside my code for the first graph in order to produce the sloping in the susceptibility? Also, for the second plot, my output produces interference fringes but the amplitude for the 535eV photon should be much lower than for the 933eV photon. I'm not too sure if it's an issue with my code or the equations that I am using though. Thank you!